# bukkit scheduler repeating

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have a problem with bukkit. I want to do a repeating task which sends a message with the coordinates of a player.
Thank you for your help!

```
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(this.main, new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Player tp = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[1]);
                            p.sendMessage("§bThe coordinates of §4" + tp.getName());
                            p.sendMessage("§eX: " + tp.getLocation().getBlockX());
                            p.sendMessage("§eY: " + tp.getLocation().getBlockY());
                            p.sendMessage("§eZ: " + tp.getLocation().getBlockZ());
                            p.sendMessage("§eD: " + tp.getLocation().getDirection());

                        }

                    }, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an **async** task to access bukkit api. Schedule a sync task instead, example using BukkitRunnable and lambda:

```
new BukkitRunnable(  () -> {

//Runnable run method, do stuff here

}).runTaskTimer (plugin, initialDelay, repeatingDelay);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it with a sync task, but it didnt work,too. I didnt use a BukkitRunnable...

Comment: Make sure to mark any answer that solves your problem as the correct solution. This helps future users with the same issue as yours!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your code here
        }
    }, initDelay, period);
```

where:

initDelay - initial delay in ticks

period - period between tasks in ticks

Comment: Thank you for your help!